# Google Cloud DataLab Notebook Save PNG

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I am using DataLab to create several dataframes and subsequent figures. I would like to save these figures to either my computer hard drive or to my Google Cloud Storage.

Normally, I would do the following (I am going through a loop so df.name changes for each graph):

```
os.chdir('C:\\Documents\\Analysis\\')
ax_plot.figure.savefig(titles[df.name] + ".png",bbox_inches='tight')
```

Is there a way to do something similar within DataLab?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Consider accepting answer by @yelsayed as it answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Copying to your computer:**

You can use [`gcloud compute copy-files`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files) to copy the files from your Datalab VM to your computer.

**Copying to GCS:**
The Datalab VM has `gsutil` installed by default, so you can do something like `gsutil cp <localfile> <gs path>`.

If you would like to do this programmatically, you can take a look at [this sample notebook](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/Storage/Storage%20APIs.ipynb) that shows how to use the built-in GCS APIs.